# Circle intersection

Tags: geometry

I've got the following hypothesis now bugging me for a while, but i was not able to come up with a proof myself or find one online.

Assume we have a collection of $N$ circles $C_i$, $i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots, N\rbrace$, in $\mathbf{R}^2$ all having the same radius and which all have a commont subset, $\bigcap\limits_i C_i \neq \emptyset$.

Having an additional cirlce $C$, to show that $C\cap \bigcap\limits_i C_i \neq \emptyset$, it sufficient to check $$C\cap C_i \cap C_j \neq \emptyset\quad \forall i,j < N$$

A real life application would be something like: We have a sender with some range. Where to put it to reach as many housholds as possible. It stems from a question posted here on math.stackexchange, i seem  not to be able to find it though.

If someone might just point me to a reference i would be very happy allready.

Comment: I don't understand what "all having equal radia where $N\geq i\in\mathbf{N}$ for which $\bigcap\limits_i C_i \neq \emptyset$." means.  Also, why not include the link to the prior question on which this is based?

Comment: @lulu simply because i was not able to find it. Maybe it was deleted in the meantime.

Comment: What do you recall about it?

Comment: Thank you for the edit; that certainly clarified your meaning.

Comment: @lulu The question dealt with a situation, where a rido tower with limited range was to be build somewhere as to reach as many households with given coordinates, as possible. The households may not necessarily be reached all simultneously. The task is, of course, to find the ideal postion. Actually just what i wrote in the question above :).

Comment: I believe what you want follows from [Helly's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem).

Comment: @lulu this theorem does exactly what OP wants (in much greater generality), you should write that up as an answer.

Comment: @lulu Please do! That seems to be just what i'm loking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Results of this type tend to follow from general considerations on intersections of convex sets.

In particular, your desired result is a special case of [Helly's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), which is considerably more general.